# Is there a reward for completing Far Cry 4?

Tags: far-cry-4

Do you get something for beating Far Cry 4?

For example, a gun or new suit?

Comment: depends on your definition of "something".

Answer (score 1):

If you are playing on console, completing the game will reward you with an achievement. Oddly enough, there is no achievements for this title on PC, through Steam.

The King Is Dead will unlock, worth [100GS on Xbox](http://www.trueachievements.com/a194721/the-king-is-dead-achievement.htm) and [a gold trophy PlayStation](http://www.playstationtrophies.org/game/far-cry-4/trophy/99272-The-King-Is-Dead.html).

> I do not think this achievement will pop if you go for the "easter egg" ending, where you simply just wait around in Pagan Mins mansion, at the start of the game.

Apart from that, the only unique reward offered comes in the form of a unique treasure, but the only thing you can do is sell it.

> IIRC, you loot the treasure from Pagan Mins body. If you initially wish to let him go, you can shoot his helicopter down with an RPG, and still loot the treasure from his body.

Answer (score -1):

Liberating certain amounts of camps, towers and doing quests will unlock different weapons, weapon upgrades, and craftable items, for the requirements just view the weapon or upgrade in the store or crafting menu